# Set CSS variables from model object in Thymeleaf

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm setting CSS color variables inside a style tag in a Thymeleaf template. The color values are coming from the model object. I also want to apply a default color, in case the model attirbute is not there.

But when I render the template, Thymeleaf doesn't evaluate the expression, but assigns the entire expression as a string literal, instead of the color value.

Below is my style tag. I've done the same thing in Apache Freemarker, and it worked fine. I'm pretty new to Thymeleaf, what should I do differently here?

```
<style>
  :root {
    --primary-color: ${brandingConfig?.themeConfig?.primaryColor} ?: '#633EA5';
    --secondary-color: ${brandingConfig?.themeConfig?.secondaryColor} ?: '#E9E6ED';
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried like `${brandingConfig.themeConfig.primaryColor} ?:'#633EA5'`?

Comment: @soorapadman Yes, I have. Though I don't think that has anything to do with the problem. I have used the safe navigation (?.) operator to handle null parent objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set CSS variables, you should use [CSS inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#css-inlining).

```
<style th:inline="css">
  :root {
    --primary-color: [(${brandingConfig?.themeConfig?.primaryColor} ?: '#633EA5')];
    --secondary-color: [(${brandingConfig?.themeConfig?.secondaryColor} ?: '#E9E6ED')];
  }
</style>
```

Normally the Thymeleaf processor only evaluates expressions in `th:*` attributes of tags.  However, if you set `th:inline="css"` on your style tag you can use `[[...]]` expressions to evaluate the text inside a tag.

Comment: Only thing is that I had to use th:inline="text" instead of th:inline="css", maybe because of an older thymeleaf version.

Comment: Yes, `th:inline="text"` will work on older version of Thymeleaf.