# Set CSS variables from model object in Thymeleaf

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm setting CSS color variables inside a style tag in a Thymeleaf template. The color values are coming from the model object. I also want to apply a default color, in case the model attirbute is not there.

I already used the correct Answer in [Question 62610602](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610602) but in my case a backslash is pasted in front of the color code. This defenetly isn't comming from the given String

```
:root {
    --accent-color: \#00FF00;
}
```

The Code in the Thymeleaf template is:

```
<style th:inline="css">
    :root {
        --accent-color: [[${appUser?.accentColorCode} ?: '#ea0a8e']];
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `[[...]]` css expressions escape output as `CSS identifiers`.  You'll have to use the unescaped `[(...)]` expression to output colors. (I've edited my original answer...)

```
<style th:inline="css">
    :root {
        --accent-color: [(${appUser?.accentColorCode} ?: '#ea0a8e')];
    }
</style>
```